# Liferay 6.2 How To Add Custom Option To Portlet Option Menu

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

[image: Liferay Portlet Options Menu]

In a Portlet Options Menu you have options such as Configuration, Import/Export.

How can I add my custom option there?

Comment: Hi Rafal, Do you want to add it to custom portlet OR Out of Box liferay's portlet?

Comment: A custom portlet.

Comment: I've also got a related questions:

Comment: I've also got related questions:
1) I know you can indirectly add options to Portlet Options (gear icon) by adding new portlet modes to a custom portlet (such as the Configuration option). But is it even possible to add there anything else than those hardcoded 9 portlet modes?
2) Can you create your own custom portlet modes? If only portlet modes can be added to that Options menu, a solution to add there a custom option would be to add a custom portlet mode.

Comment: 3) I know you can override views for portlet modes, such as view mode, edit mode. But can you override the view for Import / Export option?
4) Can you modify names of options that appear in Options menu? For example, I'd like to rename Import / Export option to Import (and override it's behavior to provide import only, but that's another thing).